# Changing state in useEffect doesn't change interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the useState and useEffect hooks in react to render a form. But when I'm updating the form using the useEffect hook. The form doesn't re-render.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";
import Input from "components/UI/Input/Input";
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
import styles from "styles/styles";
import falconAPI from "falcon-api";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function AddWarehouse(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    // State management hooks
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        warehouseType: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [
                    { value: '4', displayValue: 'Showroom' }
                ]
            },
            value: '1',
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },
        territory: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [
                    { value: '1', displayValue: 'Kandy' },
                    { value: '2', displayValue: 'Jaffna' },
                    { value: '3', displayValue: 'Colombo' },
                    { value: '4', displayValue: 'Galle' }
                ]
            },
            value: '1',
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },
        name: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Name'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        address: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Address'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        telephone: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Telephone'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
    });

    // Life cycle hooks
    useEffect(() => {
        falconAPI.post('/warehouse/type/all')
            .then(response => {
                const warehouseTypes = response.data.message;
                const updatedWarehouseTypes = []
                warehouseTypes.map(warehouseType => {
                    updatedWarehouseTypes.push({
                        value: warehouseType.id,
                        displayValue: warehouseType.name
                    });
                })
                const updatedForm = { ...form };
                updatedForm.warehouseType.options = updatedWarehouseTypes;
                setForm(updatedForm);
            })
            .catch(error => {

            });
    }, []);


    const inputChangedHandler = (e) => {

    }

    const submitFormHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(form);
    }

    const formElementsArray = [];
    for (let key in form){
        formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: form[key]
        })
    } 

    return (
        <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader color="success">
                        <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>{props.title}</h4>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        {formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
                            <Input
                                key={formElement.id}
                                elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
                                elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
                                value={formElement.config.value}
                                invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
                                shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
                                touched={formElement.config.touched}
                                changed={(event) => inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id)} />
                        ))}
                        <Button onClick={submitFormHandler}>Add Model</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
    );
}
```

In the useEffect hook, the api call update the form therefore re-rendering the warehouse type select input but the select input does not re-render. What could be the cause for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the nested values too:

```
{
        warehouseType: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [
                    { value: '4', displayValue: 'Showroom' }
                ]
            },
            value: '1',
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },

...
const updatedForm = { ...form };
                updatedForm.warehouseType.options = updatedWarehouseTypes;
                setForm(updatedForm);
```

You also missed `elementConfig` in there. `updatedForm.warehouseTypes.elementConfig.options`

But it's still a good idea to copy the nested values too.

```
const updatedForm = {
                    ...form, 
                    warehouseType: {...form.warehouseType, 
                          elementConfig: {...form.elementConfig,
                               options:updatedWarehouseTypes 
                    }}};
```

Comment: The issue was fixed when the code was changed as per your answer. But can you explain a bit more on this behavior since in when I click on the button, submitFormHandler outputs the correct updated form.

Comment: You are copying the values of the `form` using `{...form}` which is good, but the nested objects still point to the same location as before. You need to copy those values too, when you want to change them. Or else react will think the object hasn't changed.

Comment: Aha that makes sense. It seems the spread operator operates differently than I expected it to.